# Ability to 'mark' nodes and build a book functionality

Tags: nodes

I am looking for ways to do the following:

- users (both anonymous and authenticated) 'mark' nodes in some fashion to say that they want paper copies sent to them
- users can set quantity of the paper versions they require
- users get review their 'marked' nodes and potentially add/remove items from it
- users enter in address to postal system

This problem could probably be solved in several ways, what is the cleanest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 'marking' nodes, you'll definitely want the [Flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag).

Comment: The Flag module is the generally accepted way of marking nodes in an easy way but I'm not sure how the OP will handle the meta data associated to them... is it crazy to suggest a public node that has a node reference (and the associated meta data?) or is that just a permission nightmare..

Answer (score 1):

I am an advocate of the voting api for such things. It seems to fit cases where you wish to save user data against an asset (node user whatever), without making it public and with a lot of flexibility.

You can change the content-type of the vote to be something other than node, 'node-marks' for example.

The querying of votes is easy via the api or via views. It will also allow for anonymous users to mark nodes. So will tick most of your boxes.

I have used the voting api for private tagging of items (non node items) in a site I am working on and it has worked fine. It doesn't sound that dissimilar to what you are trying to achieve here.